# 401 unauthorized exception Web service

Tags: .net, web-services, iis

I am getting 401 unauthorized exception while calling an web service from an front end server, but the same code works fine in app server.

In order to verify this we have created console application to invoke the web service.
When we invoke the service from app server its working fine but same is failing in fe servers.

We have found an behavior where its not executing below piece of code in FE server.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);
```

(We have put some comments in ValidateRemoteCertificate method, we are able to see the message displaying in app server not in front end server)

1. All certificates are same in both FE and app server
2. Running with same user credentials.

Is any one face the same issue earlier or do I need to verify any configurations?

Answer (score 0):

401 are usually to do with the access to the service not SSL Certificates.  You should probebly check some of the following

If using Anonymous

- In IIS - Authentication - Make sure that Anonymous Authenication is Enabled on the Web Application
- Ensure that that the IUSR permerssion is on the folder permission you are using

If using window Auth

- In IIS - Authentication - Make sure that Windows Authenication is Enabled on the Web Application
- Ensure that that the IIS_IUSRS permerssion is on the folder permission you are using and role with the users you are wanting access.
- Ensure that you App Pool is using Network service or Delegated user account, setup correctly to use kerberos.

Hope this helps.